# MSI installed same version of application multiple times?

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I have an MSI installer in which i have below configuration:

```
<MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="A newer version of [ProductName] is already installed." AllowSameVersionUpgrades="yes"/>
```

Suppose i already installed 1.0.0.0 version.

Next time, if i install 1.0.0.1 version. It upgrades the same application as expected.

Next time, if I try to install 1.0.0.0 version. Installer does not allow me to select feature(as expected) but allow to install without selecting any feature but the top checkbox. I want here that installer should not allow to process in any case if version is down.

Another problem, If version 1.0.0.0 is installed and i open the same installer, it shows the modify, repair and remove screen as expected. But if i build the VS project and install the same version that already installed. It allow me to install and in program and feature, it shows two application with same version. I don't want this. Is there any flag or congratulation i need to use to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***ProductVersion***: Only the first three digits of **`ProductVersion`** have effect for major upgrades. Make sure you bump up at least the **third digit** and the major upgrade should work and remove the prior version(s). I would strongly recommend that you don't try to hack around with this, but simply accept the 3 digit version rule limitation. As to the question why, this is a limitation of Windows Installer. One of the worse ones.

***Automagic ProductCode***: You must have set the product code to be automatically generated. This means that every rebuild will make a new product code, and essentially set up a major upgrade to happen. This major upgrade fails because of your erroneous 4-digit version number being bumped up in the 4th digit only and two side-by-side installed versions of your application results since the major upgrade detection and running fails.